# ADAL.js not working in Microsoft personal account

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, adal.js

I have an authentication function in JavaScript using ADAL.js framework that will redirect the user to microsftonline login page. Before we can successfully authenticate using both Microsoft personal account and account created in Azure AD, but now its not working in Microsoft personal account.

This is the login page url:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=f69fde41-bc12-4a24-9833-10bef9704107&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1508%2F&state=5ec319b7-15e9-4e91-bd4d-72a06e963794&client-request-id=fa9e15f8-1210-4a61-96bc-2430b0c1a6a1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.13&nonce=a38d23bb-22f0-4053-b15f-ed15dfef6a41

It returns the below error:

```
AADSTS50020: We are unable to issue tokens from this api version for a Microsoft account. 
Please contact the application vendor as they need to use version 2.0 of the protocol to support this.
```

Here is the code i use:

```
var conf = {
                instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
                tenant: 'common',
                clientId: 'f69fde41-bc12-4a24-9833-10bef9704107',
                postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:1508/',
                cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
                callback: userSignedIn,
                redirectUri: null
            };

var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(conf);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADAL uses the Azure AD v1.0 endpoint which does not support personal Microsoft accounts.  If you want to sign in both Azure AD and personal Microsoft accounts, you can use the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint + the Microsoft authentication library (MSAL). You'll also want to re-register the application using the [application registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com).

[Here's](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2) a code sample that implements a JavaScript single page app using said library and endpoint. You can also find more documentation on v2.0 and MSAL [here](https://aka.ms/aadv2).